# How can I give a working docstring or help to a python setter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some properties that require a form of documentation with their setter. The goal is that when the user trying to populate said property, he will get a suggestion with what the property is, requirements, etc. Something like:

```
class F():
  def __init__(self):
    _x = None()

  @property
  def x(self):
    return self._x

  @x.setter
  def x(self,value):
  """ x is the path to that certain file. It must be a valid path of type .pb or .ckpt. BUT I DONT WORK """ 
    self._x = value
```

I expected:
[image]

A worse alternative would be, if something like this exists, a @help decorator or something like that, that can be called like:

```
F.x.help
```

I'm pretty flexible on finding anything that suits the same general function of providing extra info in a very intuitive and simple way. Right now I'm considering having a help(self, prop) method that you can use but I'd like something easier for the user

Comment: Is your docstring indented in your actual code and this is just a copy paste issue in your example in Stack Overflow? The code sample has a SyntaxError:  IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: oh, yea, I just wrote it as an example to simplify things. Sorry about that